# How to logout from Facebook using Spring Social

Tags: java, angularjs, facebook, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am having trouble trying to implement a logout button using the Facebook API in Spring Social.

To logout, do I have to call a URL like I did in the login button below?

I was able to implement the login calling the URL '*/connect/facebook*' as follows:

```
<form action="/connect/facebook" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="read_stream,email" />
    <md-button type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i> Login
    </md-button>
</form>
```

Also I extended the ConnectController to redirect the user to the home page:

```
@Controller
public class FacebookController extends ConnectController {

    @Inject
    public FacebookController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        super(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

    @Override
    protected String connectedView(String providerId){
        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

I am using AngularJS to fetch the user, if it is connected, below is my service responsible for it:

```
function login() {
    var request = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/home/user"
    });

    return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
}
```

And the rest controller in the backend to find or register the user:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private Facebook facebook;

    @Autowired
    private UsrService usrService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Usr findUser() {
        Usr user;

        if (!facebook.isAuthorized()) {
            return null;
        }

        String name = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getName();
        String email = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getEmail();
        byte[] avatar = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfileImage(ImageType.SQUARE);

        user = usrService.find(email);

        // saves the new user
        if (user == null) {
            user = new Usr(email, name, avatar, 0);
            user.setName(name);
            user.setAvatar(avatar);
            user.setLikes(0);
            usrService.save(user);
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any solution close to the way I implemented the login, also I checked the spring-social samples on github, but their implementations are quite different then mine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who might've been with same problem then I did:

I gave another look at spring social documentation and found out that I just needed to make a DELETE request at the '*/connect/facebook*'.

This is found at section [4.3.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/connecting.html)

Comment: If you encountered problems like "No mapping found for HTTP request /connect/facebook", you could try putting the following ConnectController in your dispatcher-servlet.xml: <beans:bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController"></beans:bean>

Comment: Does this just disconnect the app from facebook or logout the user from facebook entirely?
i.e. if the user accesses www.facebook.com, will the user be asked to login again?
I'm looking for a solution which logs the user out of facebook entirely